# If $\frac{1-3\epsilon}{2(1+\epsilon)} \le \cos\theta \le \frac{1+3\epsilon}{2(1-\epsilon)}$, then how does $\theta$ compare to $\frac{\pi}{3}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have 
$$\frac{1-3\epsilon}{2(1+\epsilon)} \le \cos\theta \le \frac{1+3\epsilon}{2(1-\epsilon)}\qquad\qquad\text{where}\quad 0 < \epsilon < 1$$

What can be said about the value of $\theta$ with respect to $\frac{\pi}{3}$? If say, $\frac{\alpha\pi}{3} \le \theta \le \frac{\beta\pi}{3}$, then what is the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Thank you.

Comment: from the assumption of $\epsilon$, you can find the supremum of $\frac{1-3\epsilon}{2(1+\epsilon)}$ and the infimum of $\frac{1+3\epsilon}{2(1-\epsilon)}$. These $2$ bounds will give you the possible values of $\theta$

Comment: Do you mean that you want the inequalities to hold for *all* $0<\epsilon<1$? If so, then taking the limit we can put $\epsilon=0$ and hence require $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}$ and hence $\theta=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n$.

Comment: @almagest , no ,not for all $\epsilon$, for some specific $\epsilon$

Comment: @SudiptaRoy Well for specific $\epsilon$ you just have $a\le\cos\theta\le b$, where $a=\frac{1-3\epsilon}{2(1+\epsilon)}$ etc. It is clear that $a\le\cos\frac{\pi}{3}\le b$. So if you want you can write $\alpha=\frac{\cos^{-1}a}{\pi/3}$ and $\beta=\frac{\cos^{-1}b}{\pi/3}$. There is not much else you can say. But for $\epsilon>0.2$ you have $b>1$ and so the upper limit is irrelevant.